# Laravel login bypass clears Session on first redirect

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Here's my issue.  When I use the login form to login, my user is able to navigate within the application with no issues with a saved session.

What I'm trying to do is create a different path to login without credentials.  For example, going to `/login_for_mike`, I store a session with the username (bypassing any login)  and then redirect them to the homepage.

The odd part is, on that redirect the session is clear and kicks me out of the application.

Now if I go back to `/login_for_mike` a second time.  It seems the session has been created and I'm good.

Something on that first redirect is not carrying over my session and after the fact, it creates a new session and then it persists.

Is there something I'm missing, or something that Laravel is skipping the first time when I hit that open route?

Here is how we handle our login:

1) User submits login form.
2) We process form by checking with our ldap server.  If suucessful, we store a session variable user.  Then we redirect to homepage.  If session variable is not set (middleware) - kick user to login page.

Other path:
1) Using a different route, we bypass the ldap check and login form.
2) We use the same code as above, however when we store the session, the middle ware checks the session and it is completely clear and kicks user to login form.
3) Now if I hit this route AGAIN, it checks the session and user is THERE! and they can proceed.

It seems, something different happens when I hit the login form, that doesnt happen when I bypass the form.

This is the pseudo code:

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('ldap', 'LdapController@ldap'); //Form posts here
Route::get('login_for_mike', 'LdapController@bypass_login');
```

**LdapController**

```
function ldap() {
    process_ldap($request->input('email'), $request->input('password')); //Works perfectly
}

function bypass_login() {
    process_ldap('mike@email.com', 0, 1); 
}

function process_ldap($user,$pass,$bypass=false)
{
    if (!$bypass)
    {
       $return = check_with_ldap_if_this_valid($user,$pass);
       if (!$return)
          Redirect::to('/login')->withErrors('Wrong credentials')->send();
    }

    Session::put('user', $user);
    Redirect::to('home-page')->send(); //This works when entering through /login/for/mike but fails on middleware for session check

}
```

**Middleware that fails when entering through /login_for_mike**

**But works if I try to hit it again after the first fail**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user=Session::get('user'); //No session when entering though /login_for_mike

    if(!$user){
         return redirect('login');

    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I would look into Laravel's `Auth::loginUsingId();` or `Auth::login();`. Instead of "bypassing" login, you could simply *force* login Mike, using either a `User` instance of Mike or the primary key for Mike from (assuming) your user's database.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm not sure that's the reason because, if I hit that same route again....it works fine.  There's something happening in the wrong order...know what I mean?

Comment: Sorta. Maybe you just worded it oddly. To me, "bypassing any login" means not logging in at all, which I could see causing issues if, for example, you have a middleware surrounding your routes that kicks you out if you're not logged in. To be honest, without seeing more of the login stuff, this will be tricky to debug from out end.

Comment: @TimLewis I've added a little more info above.  Thx.

Comment: Please show the code where you set the session and redirect

Comment: @Steve I've entered my code above.  Thanks.

Comment: Redirect::route('home-page'); (instead of ::to()?)  perhaps it is not finding the route and displaying an error page that your browser is hiding ?

Comment: Thanks @tam  I'll include more if possible.  BTW did you try with a fresh browser session?

Comment: @tam Since we are using ldap to authenticate and not our own user table, I believe this is why the decision was previously made to make sure a user is authenticated by checking whether a user is logged in via session variable / middleware.

Comment: using return redirect('url'); doesn't do anything.  Also, only time Redirect::to works is if I add the ->send() method.

Comment: are u sure redirect doesn't do anything? u would need to say `return process_ldap` in the other methods

Comment: @tam You might have corrected the whole issue.  I wasn't returning anything from process_ldap.  Let me make sure I'm not hallucinating. In the mean time, please put an answer so I can reward you.

Comment: posted as an answer. if for some reason it is not working, let me know and well discuss in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, in theory your logic is sound, but you need to make sure the controller eventually returns something.

Thus, I would rewrite your code as:

```
protected function ldap() 
{
    return $this->process_ldap($request->input('email'), $request->input('password'));
}

protected function bypass_login() 
{
    return $this->process_ldap('mike@email.com', 0, 1); 
}

private function process_ldap($user, $pass, $bypass = false)
{
    if (!$bypass) {
       $return = check_with_ldap_if_this_valid($user,$pass);
       if (!$return) {
          return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Wrong credentials');
       }
    }

    Session::put('user', $user);
    return redirect('home-page');
}
```

(Although since I was not able to reproduce your problem exactly, I am not able to explain how this directly caused your issue, but again your logic does make sense so if you call everything the way it should be used, it should work.)

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely, but I've seen it once before with hard to debug login issues.  The send() method is flushing output, and that might be telling the browser to start another connection before the session is written to the file.  The next request is sent from the browser while the session is being written to, the session is unserialized uncleanly, and you have nothing in your session at all, completely blank.  The next request should read the session properly from the initial request no matter if you go back to the login-for-mike or not.

To test this var_dump $_SESSION() on the login page.

OR

add session_write_close() before any redirect send().